# Initializing object in if condition

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to create a object but the type depends on the result of the if-condition:

```
if ([type isEqualToString:@"day"]) {
    GraphDayView *graphv = [[GraphDayView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
} else {
    GraphMonthView *graphv = [[GraphMonthView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
}
```

The problem is that graphv is out of scope, so I am not able to use it after the if-statement.
So I tried to declare it as an id:

```
id graphv;

if ([type isEqualToString:@"day"]) {
    graphv = [[GraphDayView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
} else {
    graphv = [[GraphMonthView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
}
```

But the problem now is, that the compiler doesn't know what kind of object grapv is. So:

```
graphv.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

gives an error. Anyone an idea how to solve this one?

Comment: Usually you use a common base class in such a case, is that possible here?

Answer (score 2):

If they share the same superclass, then use that instead of id.  Otherwise, create two variables and set them to nil:

```
GraphDayView *gdv = nil;
GraphMonthView *gmv = nil;
```

Then test after the if statement to see which one was initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Make GraphDayView and GraphMonthView both subclasses of GraphCalendarView.  Then make your `backgroundColor` a property of GraphCalendarView.

(Or, if your two classes are already subclasses of a UI class that implements `backgroundColor` then you're home free.)

Declare your variable as `GraphCalendarView graphv;`, and then proceed as before.  If you need to use a property/method that's unique to of one or the other of your two derived classes then cast to that class first.

Comment: Assumin both are UIView subclasses already then you could simply define the object as an instance of/reference to UIView. That would do for backgroundColor. Depending on other methods of the subclasses you may want to introduce a common superclass betwenn UIView and your subclasses, as Hot Licks suggests.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, good solution! One question though. I have a method called `setMeasurements` in both subclasses. Should I declare it as a abstract method or what is the best thing to do?

Comment: Either make them inherit from a common base class that inherits from `UIView` e.g. `@interface GraphCalendarView : UIView` then `@interface GraphMonthView : GraphCalendarView` and `@interface GraphDayView : GraphCalendarView`. OR if they don't really share any other commonality and you don't want to impose this relationship you can create a protocol that they both conform to and they can continue to inherit from `UIView`

Comment: One additional question to that. I fixed it like you mentioned. But what about my nib file. Can I just drag a uiview to my window let this view inherit from 'GraphCalendarView' and let the code decide what kind of graphview it should load? (day or month) or is it better to just completely add the graphview to my window in code?

Comment: @joostevilghost -- You can edit the nib definition and change the default parent class type from a specific class to the common base class, so long as it encompasses all of the controls you'll be linking.  But if you have any difference between the two you'll need either duplicate nibs or some runtime logic to dynamically initialize the different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
id graphv;

if ([type isEqualoString:@"day"]) {
    (GraphDayView *)graphv = [[GraphDayView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
} else {
    (GraphMonthView*)graphv = [[GraphMonthView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
}
```

Comment: That alone may make the code a bit smoother, though more liable to errors. However, graphv is still an object of id type and the compiler would still raise a warning when accessing a property or calling a method of GraphDayView or even UIView. When using ARC the compiler will even throw an error and stop the build process.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of suggestions for a common superclass have been made which are most liekly suitable.

In the event they are not then you could use typcasts. However, typecasts may cause exceptions like unknown selecor or bad_exec. If you want to savely use typcasts then you should always check either isKindOfClass or respondsToSelector.

Sample:

id someClassObject;  //or any other common superclass* instead of id

If ([something isTrue])
  someClassObject = [[AClass alloc] init]; //assuming ARC. If not then you may want to retain/autorelease here too.
else
  someClassObject = [[AClass alloc] init];

... //some code

if ([someClassObject isKindOfClass:[AClass class]]) 
  [(AClass *) someClassObject methodOfAClass];

//
if ([someClassObject isKindOfClass:[AClass class]]) {
  AClass *aClassTemp = (AClass *) someClassObject;
  [aClassTemp methodOfAClass];
  aClassTemp.propertyOfAClass = someValue; 
}

if ([someClassObject respondsToSelector:@selector(methodOfBClass:))
  [someClassObject perforformSelector:@selector(methodOfBClass:) withObject:[UIColor clearColor]];

Note the number of : following the selector name correlates to the number of parameters of the method. You may not find a suitable variance of performSelector for each possible method call. Especially as you can pass or return references to objects only.

Again, both of them I would only suggest if the common subclass is not suitable in your case.